# Cannot get Pi working as a simple bridge

Tags: raspbian, bridge

I have a RaspberryPi 4, and need it to connect to an Ethernet printer/ scanner.

I have looked at many articles and I think that as not one worked, now there are problems as a result!

The bizarre point is that I might be able to print - but I cannot ping the device! Its web server showing status, ... has stopped working, and sane/ xsane cannot "see" the scanner!

My ideal would be that the printer appears seamlessly across the network, so I may print/ scan as though the device is on the local network.

My main network is on e.g. 192.168.0.xxx, with the router as 192.168.0.1.

The Pi is set up with a static ip address as 192.168.0.10 - and there are no issues with accessing it from the main network.

The printer originally was on a static ip address as 192.168.0.14.

I set up the Ethernet port on the Pi to be 192.168.1.13 - and that I can see as being valid on the Pi.

I then changed the printer to be 192.168.1.14, and kept the netmask unchanged as 255.255.255.0, and the gateway I changed to be 192.168.1.13 rather than being the router.

If I run nmap -sn on the pi to cover the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet, it only sees the Pi Ethernet port.

I added a bridge using nmcli con - and see:-

```
nmcli con show
NAME             UUID           TYPE      DEVICE 
br0              [bridge UUID]  bridge    br0    
WiFi Connection  [wifi UUID]    ethernet  --
```

If I look at my iptables (about which I know nothing!) I get:-

```
sudo iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

If there is a simple way to get the printer/ scanner to work across the network, I would be delighted - it seemed so simple until I tried!

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You claim to have done various things (but failed to mention HOW). You claim to be running "raspbian" which is meaningless. You have a printer on a different subnet. You mention "bridge" but fail to explain how it is configured. I suggest you get rid of what you have done (including static IP addresses) and let the router do its job of assigning addresses using DHCP. If you want a bridge (WHY) you assign an address to this NOT the bridged interfaces.

Comment: this appears to be an XY question  ... you believe that a bridge is the solution to an unspecified problem, so you ask about the bridge, instead of asking about the actual problem

Comment: Many thanks for your help. The reason I added a bridge was following many "solutions" to being able to access a printer attached to the ethernet port on the Pi - from across the network.
I have tried DHCP and it didn't work; I have tried without the bridge, and it didn't work - but if there are instructions as to how to get the printer/ scanner accessible across the network seamlessly, I would love to try.
Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just connect the printer to your router (like most of us do)?

Comment: Because they are in completely different rooms, and the device I used to make the connection has broken, and I cannot get a replacement, so I thought (having read some articles) that I could use the Pi to connect to the printer, which seemed like the most sensible solution!